# Access property of a directive from parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `datetime` directive that contains two properties in its scope: `date` and `time`. How can I access these properties from the parent controller? I tried doing this

```
<div id="inputs" ng-controller="InputCtrl">
    Start: <datetime ng-model="start"></datetime>
    End: <datetime ng-model="end"></datetime>

    You have chosen to start on {{start.date}}, {{start.time}} 
    and end on {{end.date}}, {{end.time}}.
</div>
```

The values for `start.date`, `start.time`, `end.date`, and `end.time` are not being populated when I change the input. How can I access the directive scope from the parent controller?

Here is my directive code:

```
angular.module("components", [])
    .directive("datetime", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.time = "12:00 PM";
                $scope.date = "12/01/2013";
            },
            template: 
                '<div><div class="control-group input-append">' +
                '<input class="input-small" type="text" ng-model="date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" bs-datepicker>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="control-group input-append">' +
                '<input type="text" class="input-small" ng-model="time" bs-timepicker>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="timepicker"><i class="icon-time"></i></button>' +
                '</div></div>',
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

Comment: Are you defining the directive with isolated scope?

Comment: @DavinTryon I believe so, yes.

Comment: kindly share your directive code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind your directive scope variables to your directive attributes, like this:

```
angular.module("components", [])
    .directive("datetime", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                model: "=ngModel"
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.model.time = "12:00 PM";
                $scope.model.date = "12/01/2013";
            },
            template: 
                '<div><div class="control-group input-append">' +
                '<input class="input-small" type="text" ng-model="date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" bs-datepicker>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="control-group input-append">' +
                '<input type="text" class="input-small" ng-model="time" bs-timepicker>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="timepicker"><i class="icon-time"></i></button>' +
                '</div></div>',
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

`"=ngModel"` means that you are binding `model` in your isolated scope to the variable in `ng-model` in your parent scope.